# Start a job multiple times concurrently with workflow plugin

Tags: groovy, jenkins, jenkins-workflow

I am trying to run one job 5 times concurrently using the workflow plugin. here is the snippet:

```
def concurrent=[:]
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
concurrent["concurrent${i}"] = {
build job: 'test_job', parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name:'queue', value:     
'automation_prod.q'],[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name:'dummy', value: "${i}"]]
    }
}
parallel concurrent
```

this snippet causes the  the test_job to run only once.
I need it running 5 times concurrently.

thanks!

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31387614/parallel-jobs-using-build-flow-plugin-with-loop-in-jenkins/31388574#31388574  Think it's a duplicate question

Comment: I dont think it quiet describes my problem. and the solution here is using build flow and not workflow. it's different syntax.

Comment: I see you're building a Map of Closures, but what does the Closure do? It looks like it's supposed to return a Map, but it's missing the outer brackets. I'm surprised the code compiled.

Comment: I'm not really sure. just tried to perform according to an example I saw online

Comment: Where is this example?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!topic/jenkinsci-users/UMG8hcg7G2Q and https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!topic/jenkinsci-users/RqQfFLYSwXc tried to create something from both threads.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no bug in Workflow here beyond a lack of diagnosis for the mistake in the script. In Groovy, the loop counter `i` is defined in an enclosing scope and mutated, so by the time each closure runs, it has the same value: 5. You can see this, as well as the concept behind the fix, outside Jenkins:

```
$ groovy -e 'def cs = []; for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {def j = i; cs += {println "${i} vs. ${j}"}}; for (c in cs) {c()}'
5 vs. 0
5 vs. 1
5 vs. 2
5 vs. 3
5 vs. 4
```

In your case, Jenkins saw five attempts to schedule the same downstream project with the same parameters, and coalesced them all into one queue item and thus one build. (Depending on timing, it might have started one downstream build before other `build` steps even ran, in which case it would run a second downstream build, but generally it would be fewer than five total builds.)

[This new test](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-plugin/pull/196/files) demonstrates that what you wanted to do is indeed possible; you just need to capture the *current* value of the loop variable in a new lexically-scoped variable outside the closure.

By the way

```
def cs = []; (0..4).each {i -> cs += {println i}}; cs*.call()
```

does work as expected from command-line Groovy, since there is no mutated loop variable. Unfortunately this syntax is not yet available in Workflow: [JENKINS-26481](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26481)

Beware that you should **not** be using a “dummy” parameter value to differentiate queue entries. While this may happen to work today, expect that behavior to be fixed, so that parameter values specified by `build` which do not correspond to any parameter actually defined in the downstream project will either be skipped with a warning, or result in an error. If you think you need a dummy parameter, you are probably doing something else wrong, but it is impossible to advise what that is without any explanation of why you would want a downstream project to run multiple times with nothing in its input differentiating the builds.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. in my case. each job is a runs a worker on a different machine that pulls data from t a rabbitmq queue and sends it somewhere. if I want to run 5 workers on 5 different machines - it makes total sense running the same job with the same params.

Comment: In that case it makes sense to run the job concurrently, but define a real parameter for the parallelism counter.