# How can I dynamically generate parallel jobs with jenkins workflow/pipeline

Tags: groovy, jenkins-workflow

So I'm trying to generate a variable number of test jobs to run in parallel, but I'm running into a situation where the parameter being passed in will be the max value for all executions.

here is a simplified version of the groovy code that I am using

```
jobs=[:]
unitSplits = 5
println "split units $unitSplits times"

for (int i = 0; i < unitSplits; i++) {
  jobs["unit tests ${i} of ${unitSplits}"] =  { 
      group -> {-> test(group)}
    }(i)
}

jobs.each{ k, v -> v() }

def test(group) {
  println "testing group ${group}"
}
```

expected output:

```
split units 5 times
testing group 0
testing group 1
testing group 2
testing group 3
testing group 4
```

Actual output:

```
split units 5 times
testing group 5
testing group 5
testing group 5
testing group 5
testing group 5
```

I need this `group` parameter to know which group of tests to run.

Any ideas how to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a Groovy mistake, and in fact there is another `jenkins-workflow` question discussing it. Your `int i` is a single *variable* scoped to the loop and shared by each closure; at the end of the loop (before any closures have been run!), it has its final value, 5. The easiest fix to use `def` to create a new (effectively `final`) variable inside each loop iteration, for example:

```
def _i = i
```

By the way `.each` is not going to work due to [JENKINS-26481](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26481); you must use simpler C-style loops for now. Anyway I suppose your real example would be using the `parallel` step.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32228590/start-a-job-multiple-times-concurrently-with-workflow-plugin for example.

Comment: Yes, you are correct to assume that the real example would use parallel step, doing without made it easy to test in a groovyConsole session.