# How to start jobs(parallel) from the main job with different inputs in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am using jenkins and having scripted syntax in jenkinsfile
In the main job after source checkout I need to run other job `n` times (parallel)  with different inputs .
Any tips to start this?

```
def checkout(repo, branch) {

checkout(changelog: false,
        poll: false,
        scm: [$class                           : 'GitSCM',
              branches                         : [[name: "*/${branch}"]],
              doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
              recursiveSubmodules              : true,
              extensions                       : [[$class: 'LocalBranch', localBranch: "${branch}"]],
              submoduleCfg                     : [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: '', url: "${repo}"]]])


withCredentials([[$class          : '',

                  credentialsId   : '',

                  passwordVariable: '',

                  usernameVariable: '']]) {


    sh "git clean -f && git reset --hard origin/${branch}"
}
}

node("jenkins02") {

stage('Checkout') {
    checkout gitHubRepo, gitBranch
}

}
```

Comment: what is the number of n?

Comment: I mean run n times

Comment: how big a n can be, is n<10? 10<n<100? , 100<n<1000 ?

Comment: we are creating white label app .it is number of clients.
so it is difficult to predict. but let's think <100

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Start a job multiple times concurrently with workflow plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32228590/start-a-job-multiple-times-concurrently-with-workflow-plugin)

Answer (score 1):

We do this by storing all the jobs we want to run in a Map and then pass it into the parallel step for execution. So you just setup the different params and add each definition into the map, then execute.

```
    Map jobs = [:]
    jobs.put('job-1', {
        stage('job-1') {
            node {
                build(job: "myorg/job-1/master", parameters: [new StringParameterValue('PARAM_NAME','VAL1')], propagate: false)
            }
        }
    })
    jobs.put('job-2', {
        stage('job-2') {
            node {
                build(job: "myorg/job-2/master", parameters: [new StringParameterValue('PARAM_NAME','VAL2')], propagate: false)
            }
        }
    })
    parallel(jobs)
```